# Как поставить пробел между числами в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' 
+ $('#res').append(' ').text() + $('#res1').append(' ').text();
```

не могу понять как поставит пробел, который бы разделял числа
`$('#res').append(' ').text()` - содержит произвольное число например 1000

```
$('#res1').append(' ').text() - содержит тоже произвольное число например 0001
```

эти два числа я записываю в файл(*.txt), на данный момент запись в файле такая 10000001 как мне разделить эти числа пробелом или же перевести на другую строку ?
Хочу добиться такого результата:

1000 0001

---

1000
0001

Comment: `append()` применяется для добавления элемента в DOM, а не для прибавления пробелов к тексту.

Comment: $('#res').text() + ' ' + $('#res1').text();

Comment: сделай [mcve], все выглядит рабочим

Comment: @teran пробовал, не работает так. Пробел не ставит

Comment: @teran, а пробел где? `$('#res').text() + '  ' + $('#res1').text();`

Comment: @Other, нужно что-то другое пробовать, не работает так. Записывает числа в одну строку без пробелов.

Comment: @Other есть там пробел у меня, мышкой можно выделить. в `код` забыл выделить строку, так не очень видно

Comment: @teran, забыли - может быть, но автору это не поможет.

Comment: @Other не поможет, пока не научится вопросы задавать корректно. а не просто "добавить пробел в строку". В строку то пробел нормально добавится таким образом. А что с ней дальше автор делать собирается это другой вопрос, про который автор умолчал.

Comment: @teran, нет, тут всё верно. Вы, может, и верно ответили, с пробелом, но из-за оплошности ценность ответа утрачена, так что...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно закодировать данные функцией [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).
И нужен атрибут [`download`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/a/download):

```js
let f = document.querySelector('#f'),
    s = document.querySelector('#s'),
    d = document.querySelector('#d'),
    l = document.createElement('A');

l.setAttribute('download', 'fileName.scv');
document.body.appendChild(l);

d.addEventListener('click', e => {
  l.href = `data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(f.value + ' ' + s.value)}`;
  l.click();
});
```

```html
F num: <input type='text' id='f' value='123' /><br />
S num: <input type='text' id='s' value='456' /><br /><br />
<input type='button' id='d' value='Download' />
```